# Rocket not parsing RawStr in a URL to match route

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

The [guide on Rocket's site](https://rocket.rs/guide/requests/) suggests that dynamic routes can be ranked. The example uses different types for the dynamic portion as the matching criteria for the routes.  When I put a url with anything other than a `usize`, I get the following error:

```
GET /user/three text/html:
    => Matched: GET /user/<id>
    => Failed to parse 'id': RawStr("three")
    => Outcome: Forward
    => Error: No matching routes for GET /user/three text/html.
    => Warning: Responding with 404 Not Found catcher.
    => Response succeeded.
```

The code I'm using:

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(rocket_codegen)]

extern crate rocket;
use rocket::http::RawStr;

#[get("/user/<id>")]
fn user(id: usize) -> String { format!("First rank") }

#[get("/user/<id>", rank = 2)]
fn user_int(id: isize) -> String { format!("second rank") }

#[get("/user/<id>", rank = 3)]
fn user_str(id: &RawStr) -> String { format!("last rank") }

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![user]).launch();
}
```

I would expect instead of a `404 error` a page at `/user/three` displaying the test `last rank`.  Why is it not doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rocket doesn't know about your routes *unless you tell it about them*:

```
fn main() {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![user, user_int, user_str]).launch();
    //                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Yes, just figured that out this second.

Comment: For reference, see the [Mounting section](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/overview/#mounting) in the Rocket guide: *The `mount` method takes as input: ... A list of routes via the `routes!` macro.*